# How should i get the data from sourceJson in android using volley?

Tags: android, json, android-studio, android-volley

Below is the response what i am getting i want to get the data from "SourceJson" m not ble to understnd why i am getting "" in source json please help me

```
{
    "incomingOrder": [
        {
            "Namw": 8510,
            "Surname": "00",
            "mob": "00",
            "phone": "000",
            "SourceJson": "{\"cart_gst\":30.21,\"instructions\":\"\",\"order_packing_charges\":30,\"cart_igst_percent\":0,\"cart_sgst\":15.1038,}",
            "test": "NotSynced",
            "test": "DPA",
}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :

```
requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        JsonObjectRequest obreq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, JsonURL,
                // The third parameter Listener overrides the method onResponse() and passes
                //JSONObject as a parameter
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    // Takes the response from the JSON request
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("incomingOrder");

                            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

                            JSONObject objSourceJson=jsonObject.getJSONObject("SourceJson");

                            Log.i("IvaSourceJson",objSourceJson.toString());

                            String cart_gst=objSourceJson.getString("cart_gst");
                            String instructions=objSourceJson.getString("instructions");
                        }
                        // Try and catch are included to handle any errors due to JSON
                        catch (JSONException e) {
                            // If an error occurs, this prints the error to the log
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                // The final parameter overrides the method onErrorResponse() and passes VolleyError
                //as a parameter
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    // Handles errors that occur due to Volley
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("Volley", "Error");
                    }
                }
        );
        // Adds the JSON object request "obreq" to the request queue
        requestQueue.add(obreq);
```

Comment: getting error "SourceJson of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject"

Comment: "SourceJson": "{\"cart_gst\":30.21,\"instructions\":\"\",\"order_packing_charges\":30,\"cart_igst_percent\":0,\"cart_sgst\":15.1038,}"

Comment: Sorry but i didn't get it

Comment: This SourceJson is also a string so you should parse this string to json. Use Json parser

Comment: Also this is not a valid Json. there is a comma(,) at last before closing the braze. Try to get a valid Json first.

Answer (score 0):

As it is JSONArray data is of list type, better not to use `jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);`.
Use this code for multiple results,

```
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "", new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("Response", response);
            try {
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);

                JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("incomingOrder");
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject object1 = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    String name = object1.getString("Namw");
                    String surname = object1.getString("Surname");
                    String mob = object1.getString("mob");
                    String phone = object1.getString("phone");
                    String sourceJson = object1.getString("SourceJson");
                    String test = object1.getString("test");
                    String test1 = object1.getString("test");
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("Error", error.getMessage());
        }
    });
    Context context;
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    queue.add(request);
```

Code this in any method and call the method where the action needed.